# How to use method "scannerOpenWithScan()" and filter string in thrift's C++ to access HBase

Tags: filter, hbase, thrift

^_^ Hi, everyone:

How can I use method "scannerOpenWithScan()"  and filterString in thrift's C++.
 The hbase version is hbase-0.92.1.

I want to select rows depending on the value of the column, so I added the scannerOpenWithScan() to the "examples/thrift/DemoClient.cpp":

```
/**
* open a scanner with scan (filter string)
*/
320     TScan tscan;
321     std::string filterStr;
322     filterStr = "SingleColumnValueFilter (<=, '25', 'entry', 'num', true, false)";
323     tscan.__set_filterString(filterStr);       
324         
325     std::cout << "Starting scanner with scan..." << std::endl;
326     scanner = client.scannerOpenWithScan(t, tscan); 
327     std::cout << "The scanner id is " << scanner << std::endl;
328     try { ...... }
```

But there is no scanner id returned,  the error is:

```
Starting scanner with scan...
ERROR: No more data to read.
```

The thrift.log error is:

```
796 java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Incorrect filter string SingleColumnValueFilter(<=, '25', 'entry', 'num', true, false)
797         at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.filter.ParseFilter.parseSimpleFilterExpression(ParseFilter.java:250)
798         at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.filter.ParseFilter.parseFilterString(ParseFilter.java:168)
799         at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.thrift.ThriftServer$HBaseHandler.scannerOpenWithScan(ThriftServer.java:766)
```

the thrift.out is:

```
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
  6         at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
  7         at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
  8         at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
  9         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:616)
 10         at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.filter.ParseFilter.parseSimpleFilterExpression(ParseFilter.java:240)
 11         at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.filter.ParseFilter.parseFilterString(ParseFilter.java:168)
 12         at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.thrift.ThriftServer$HBaseHandler.scannerOpenWithScan(ThriftServer.java:766)
 13         at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.thrift.generated.Hbase$Processor$scannerOpenWithScan.getResult(Hbase.java:3821)
```

I have no idea about it. Does anyone know how to use C++ with filter features to access HBase?

Answer (score 6):

Now I know the answer: the filter string is Incorrect, the correct is:

```
filterStr = "SingleColumnValueFilter('entry', 'num', =, 'substring:25', true, false)";
```

The correct syntax is:

```
SingleColumnValueFilter('<family>', '<qualifier>', <compare operator>, '<comparator>', <filterIfColumnMissing_boolean>, <latest_version_boolean>)
```

details at 
   https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HBASE-5946

Comment: How to form the filter string for Compound filters. i.e., SingleColumnFilter AND SingleColumnFilter OR SingleColumnFilter